# Mute left/Right channel in windows

Tags: windows, audio, sound-card

I am developing an application which requires me to mute left/right individually while listening to continuous audio output via headphone/earphone. I have tried the following options in windows 7, 8,8.1,10 laptops,

- **Adjusting the balance levels in playback device settings** - My playback device is speaker, i tried adjusting the levels by keeping Left channel to zero and listening to right, i can still hear some sound in my left earphone. (try this with some continuous music)
- **Disabling all enhancements, updating audio driver, used a TRS earphone instead of TRRS** - Still hearing some sound.
- **Tried with apps like VLC Player, Volumouse (Nirsoft), Volume2 etc**. - None of them work.

-**Downgraded my audio driver to older vista version** - Reverts back to new one

Is there any means to actually do this or is it a windows restriction which does not allow you to do this.

Any help guys.!

Comment: This is highly dependend on the drivers that come with the hardware, but being a mucisian myself, why not just edit the wave file, convert to stereo if its not yet stereo, and then mute one channel completely and save as separate track and play that back? That way you can be sure it will only play on one channel.

Comment: You are assuming that the OP is listening to recorded sound. You may be right.